# Really weird... can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'lxml.etree._Element'

Tags: python, mocking, lxml, monkeypatching

I've changed attributes for other classes before without issues. _Element is obviously not a built-in.

```
from lxml.etree import _Element
_Element.new_attr = 54
```

results in:

TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'lxml.etree._Element'

Comment: Works fine if I use forbiddenfruit as a workaround.  Still really curious as to why this is necessary

Answer (score 1):

`_Element` is [implemented in Cython](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/etree.pyx#L695). As [Steve Holden explains](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-February/474526.html) (my emphasis),

> The problem is that extension types' attributes are determined by
>   the layout of the object's slots and forever fixed in the C code that
>   implements them: **the slots can't be extended, so there's no way to add
>   attributes**. This is an efficiency feature: it would be *extremely* slow
>   to look up the basic types' attributes using late-binding (it would also
>   change the nature of the language somewhat, making it more like Ruby or
>   Self).

and Guido van Rossum explains why [this is by-design](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-February/474526.html):

> This is prohibited intentionally to prevent accidental fatal changes
>   to built-in types (fatal to parts of the code that you never though
>   of). Also, it is done to prevent the changes to affect different
>   interpreters residing in the address space, since built-in types
>   (unlike user-defined classes) are shared between all such
>   interpreters.

Comment: Guido van Rossum Updated link https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-February/077180.html

Answer (score 0):

The `_Element` class is from a Cython compiled binary module. These are not Python 1st citizen objects and you cannot add arbitrary attributes to such objects.