# How to access instance dictionary after overriding __dict__ attribute on its class?

Tags: python, class, python-internals

Consider this example where the `__dict__` of all instances of a class `A` will point to a global dict `shared`.

```
shared = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = shared
```

Now let's test a few things:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> a.a, a.b, b.a, b.b
(1, 2, 1, 2)
>>> b.x = 100
>>> shared
{'a': 1, 'x': 100, 'b': 2}
>>> a.x
100
>>> c = A()
>>> c.a, c.b, c.x
(1, 2, 100)
>>> shared['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> a.foo, b.foo, c.foo
('bar', 'bar', 'bar')
>>> a.__dict__, b.__dict__, c.__dict__
({'a': 1, 'x': 100, 'b': 2, 'foo': 'bar'},
 {'a': 1, 'x': 100, 'b': 2, 'foo': 'bar'},
 {'a': 1, 'x': 100, 'b': 2, 'foo': 'bar'}
)
```

All works as expected.

---

Now let's tweak class `A` a little by adding an attribute named `__dict__`.

```
shared = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

class A(object):
    __dict__ = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = shared
```

Let's run the same set of steps again:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> a.a, a.b, b.a, b.b
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> b.x = 100
>>> shared
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> b.__dict__  # What happened to x?
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> a.x
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'x'
>>> c = A()
>>> c.a, c.b, c.x
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> shared['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> a.foo, b.foo, c.foo
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> a.__dict__, b.__dict__, c.__dict__
({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'foo': 'bar'},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'foo': 'bar'},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'foo': 'bar'}
)
>>> b.x  # Where did this come from?
100
```

---

Based on the above information the first case worked as expected but the second one didn't and hence I would like to know what changed after the adding class level `__dict__` attribute. And can we access the instance dictionary being used now in any way?

Comment: You shouldn't be adding attributes with leading and trailing double underscore characters which is reserved for system-defined names. See [**Reserved classes of identifiers**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers).

Comment: @martineau I am aware of that. But that's not the point of this question.

Comment: So you're wanting to know a workaround for something that was broken because you're not following the guidelines (which exist for a reason).

Comment: @martineau Yes. But only for learning purpose. I won't be doing something similar in actual code.

Comment: Can't you just access an instance's dictionary explicitly via something like `a.__dict__['foo']`?

Comment: @martineau: No, because in this weird setup, that's actually the wrong dict.

Comment: @user2357112: How so? It seems to work for me (using Python 2.7.13).

Comment: @martineau: It's not the one `a` is using to store its instance attributes; it's an entirely unrelated dict. You can see in the example that the attributes actually available on the `A` instances aren't consistent with the entries in the `__dict__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case the `self.__dict__` has access to the `__dict__` descriptor provided by its type. This descriptor allows it to get the underlying instance dictionary and also set it to a new one using [`PyObject_GenericGetDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a66f9c6bb134561a24374f10e8c35417d356ce14/Objects/dictobject.c#L4312) and [`PyObject_GenericSetDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a66f9c6bb134561a24374f10e8c35417d356ce14/Objects/object.c#L1286) respectively.

```
>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy(
{'__module__': '__main__',
 '__init__': <function A.__init__ at 0x1041fb598>,
 '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
 '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None
})
>>> A.__dict__['__dict__'].__get__(a)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

And of course we can set a new dictionary from here as well:

```
>>> new_dict = {}
>>> A.__dict__['__dict__'].__set__(a, new_dict)  # a.__dict__ = new_dict
>>> a.spam = 'eggs'
>>> a.__dict__
{'spam': 'eggs'}
>>> new_dict
{'spam': 'eggs'}
>>> b = A()  # Points to `shared`
>>> b.__dict__
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

---

In the second case our class itself contains an attribute named `__dict__`, but still the `__dict__` attribute points to `mappingproxy`.

```
>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy(
{'__module__': '__main__',
 '__dict__': None,
 '__init__': <function A.__init__ at 0x1041cfae8>,
 '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
 '__doc__': None}
)
```

`__dict__` attribute for classes in this way is a [special attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877290/what-is-the-dict-dict-attribute-of-a-python-class).

```
>>> A.__weakref__ is A.__dict__['__weakref__']
True    
>>> A.__weakref__ = 1    
>>> A.__weakref__, A.__dict__['__weakref__']
(1, 1)

>>> A.__dict__ = {}    
AttributeError: attribute '__dict__' of 'type' objects is not writable
```

The attribute we had set can be accessed like this:

```
>>> repr(A.__dict__['__dict__'])
'None'
```

---

A Python level we have now lost access to the instance dictionary but internally a class can find it using [`tp_dictoffset`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dictoffset). As done in [`_PyObject_GetDictPtr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a66f9c6bb134561a24374f10e8c35417d356ce14/Objects/object.c#L966).

Both [`__getattribute__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L1207) and [`__setattr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a66f9c6bb134561a24374f10e8c35417d356ce14/Objects/object.c#L1280) also access the underlying instance dictionary using `_PyObject_GetDictPtr`.

To access the instance dictionary being used we can actually implement `_PyObject_GetDictPtr` in Python using ctypes. This is pretty eloquently done by @user4815162342 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24498525/846892).

```
import ctypes

def magic_get_dict(o):
    # find address of dict whose offset is stored in the type
    dict_addr = id(o) + type(o).__dictoffset__

    # retrieve the dict object itself
    dict_ptr = ctypes.cast(dict_addr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.py_object))
    return dict_ptr.contents.value
```

Continuing the second case:

```
>>> magic_get_dict(a)
{'__dict__': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'foo': 'bar'}}  # `a` has only one attribute i.e. __dict__
>>> magic_get_dict(b)
{'__dict__': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'foo': 'bar'}, 'x': 100}  # `x` found
>>> magic_get_dict(b).update(shared)
>>> b.a, b.b, b.foo, b.x
(1, 2, 'bar', 100)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could access `_PyObject_GetDictPtr` directly through `ctypes.pythonapi._PyObject_GetDictPtr`. You'd need to set the argtypes and restype manually, though.