# How can I fake sys.stdout.istty in a test case without conflicting with pytest stdout capturing?

Tags: mocking, pytest

I need to fake the return value of `sys.stdout.istty()` in a test case. Monkeypatching with `monkeypatch.setattr("sys.stdout.isatty", lambda: True)` is no option because it conflicts with pytest stdout capturing when using option `-s`. How can I fake on the test case level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python does not allow monkey-patching built-in types such as file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24498525/5308983). [`sys.stdout` is a file object.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) The patch has to be applied in the production code module namespace (`<module>.sys.stdout`). When using `pytest-mock` (fixture `mocker`) this looks as follows:

```
def test_of_prod_code_with_dependency(mocker):
    stdout_mock = mocker.patch("<module>.sys.stdout")
    stdout_mock.isatty.return_value = istty

    # production code which depends on sys.stdout.isatty() comes here
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using monkeypatch of pytest

To use a lambda as a function, you need to parenthesize it.

```py
import pytest

def test_stdout_istty(monkeypatch):
    # To use a lambda as a function, you need to parenthesize it.
    monkeypatch.setattr("sys.stdout.isatty", (lambda: True))
    #                                        ^            ^
    assert sys.stdout.isatty() == True
    assert sys.stdout.isatty() == False
```

## Using a unittest mock

```py
import pytest
from unittest import mock

def test_stdout_istty():
    with mock.patch('sys.stdout') as stdout:
        stdout.isatty.return_value = False
        assert sys.stdout.isatty() == False
        assert sys.stdout.isatty() == True
        # if your code contains stdout.isatty, 
        # then put inside of the context manager.
```